# How do I throttle a slider's value change event?

Tags: silverlight, mvvm, system.reactive, throttling

I got a slider that on value change forces a fairly serious computation, so I want to throttle it to fire actual event after for example 50ms pass when user has finished sliding it.

While I learned some various stuff about Rx its unclear how should I approach this using MVVM pattern.

In my current MVVM approach I got slider value bound to my viewModel. I would prefer to add Rx throttle with minimal possible impact on existing code (as a beginning at least).

Ive seen some other threads about MVVM and Rx and I don't think they lead me to some exact direction with my problem. I see various possible approaches and would like not to invent a bycicle.

Comment: Fair enough, but please trust our tags system.  You can get an RSS feed on, say, the [system.reactive] *tag*, but you can't get a feed of questions that have "system reactive" in the title.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

In this case, you should bind to the PropertyChanged event of your ViewModel, something like:

```
Observable.FromEvent<PropertyChangedEventArgs>(x => this.PropertyChanged +=x, x => this.PropertyChanged -= x)
    .Where(x => x.PropertyName == "SliderName")
    .Select(_ => this.SliderName)
    .Throttle(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(50));
```

Or, if you were using [ReactiveUI](http://www.reactiveui.net), it'd look like this:

```
this.WhenAnyValue(x => x.SliderName)
    .Throttle(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(50), RxApp.DeferredScheduler);
```

Comment: In the ViewModel, the View should be binding to a meaningful property on the ViewModel

Comment: So if I'm understanding this correctly do you then need something to subscribe to this observable?

Comment: Yeah, you'd maybe do .Subscribe(x => DebouncedSliderValue = x), or maybe actually take the action that you were going to do, like .Subscribe(x => RecalculateTheStuff(x))

Answer (score -7):

Lets just outline the problem.  You have a View Model which has some `double` typed Property.  When a value is assigned to this property a fairly expensive calculation takes place.  Wouldn't normally be a problem but when the UI binds the value of a `Slider` to this property the rapid changes generated does create a problem.

First decision to be made is between the view and view-model which is responsible for dealing with this problem.  It could be argued both ways the View-Model has "chosen" to make a property assignment an expensice operatione on the other hand the View has "chosen" to assign the property using a `Slider`.

My choice would be on view side of things because thats a better place to implement this.  However rather than fiddle with the View directly I would build a new `Control` to add the feature.  Let's call it the `DelaySlider`.  It will derive from `Silder` and have two additional dependency properties `Delay` and `DelayedValue`.  The `DelayedValue` will match the existing value of `Value` property but only after `Delay` milliseconds have elapsed since the last `Value` changed.

Here is the full code for the control:-

```
public class DelaySlider : Slider
{
    private DispatcherTimer myTimer;

    private bool myChanging = false;

    #region public double DelayedValue
    public double DelayedValue
    {
        get { return (double)GetValue(DelayedValueProperty); }
        set { SetValue(DelayedValueProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty DelayedValueProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register(
            "DelayedValue",
            typeof(double),
            typeof(DelaySlider),
            new PropertyMetadata(0.0, OnDelayedValuePropertyChanged));

    private static void OnDelayedValuePropertyChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        DelaySlider source = d as DelaySlider;
        if (source != null && !source.myChanging)
        {
            source.Value = (double)e.NewValue;
        }
    }
    #endregion public double DelayedValue

    #region public int Delay

    public int Delay
    {
        get { return (int)GetValue(DelayProperty); }
        set { SetValue(DelayProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty DelayProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register(
            "Delay",
            typeof(int),
            typeof(DelaySlider),
            new PropertyMetadata(0, OnDelayPropertyChanged));

    private static void OnDelayPropertyChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        DelaySlider source = d as DelaySlider;
        if (source != null)
        {
            source.OnDelayPropertyChanged((int)e.OldValue, (int)e.NewValue);
        }
    }

    private void OnDelayPropertyChanged(int oldValue, int newValue)
    {
        if (myTimer != null)
        {
            myTimer.Stop();
            myTimer = null;
        }

        if (newValue > 0)
        {
            myTimer = new DispatcherTimer();
            myTimer.Tick += myTimer_Tick;

            myTimer.Interval = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(newValue);
        }
    }

    void myTimer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        myTimer.Stop();
        myChanging = true;
        SetValue(DelayedValueProperty, Value);
        myChanging = false;
    }
    #endregion public int Delay


    protected override void OnValueChanged(double oldValue, double newValue)
    {
        base.OnValueChanged(oldValue, newValue);
        if (myTimer != null)
        {
            myTimer.Start();
        }

    }
}
```

Now replace your `Silder` with `DelaySlider` and bind your View-Model property to the `DelayedValue` and specify your millisecond delay value in its `Delay` property.

You now have a useful re-usable control, you haven't messed about with nasty tricks in the View, you have no additional code in the code-behind of the view, the View-Model is unchanged and undisturbed and you haven't had to do include the Rx stuff at all.

Comment: Hmm Anthony, I wonder, do you dislike Rx in general? When I look at this and another answer I think another is much more clean. Also imagine that I am using some advanced slider from paid controls library, I migh't be unable to create my own, but with delay so easily. Actually In my case I am using range slider which is fairly complex by itself without a couple of timers on both values, so In my case I think Rx is way better. Adding a reference on RX assembly and rewriting a few lines of code can't be tooo bad.

Comment: Lol, my solution is 2 lines long. This is a textbook reason as to why you *should* use Rx.

Comment: @Valentin: Please re-read my first paragraph.  Does it describe the scenario that you are facing well enough?

Comment: @Paul: I'm going to stick to my guns here.

Comment: Couple issues with the above code: 1) Without Rx it is pretty hard to understand what is going on. 2) It doesn't implement throttling, but rather delays updates until Value stops changing, i.e. if I keep moving slider DelayedValue will not change until I stop. Issues like that make Rx tax worth paying in most cases.

Comment: @Denis re. your point #2, Throttle has the same behavior actually - however, it wouldn't be hard to create the behavior you describe

Comment: @Denis: I also disagree with point 1 and Paul where "short" seems to be equated with "Simple".  The vast majority of the code above is simple boiler plate Dependency property code which was created with a snippet.  However the really important point is that its done __once__ and then the resulting control can be re-used.  Whereas using Rx requires a) a developer to understand Rx (a SL dev really ought to grasp simple DPs but I wouldn't demand they know Rx) and b) its there __each__ time its used in your View model code. Each time a dev reading the code has to stop and ask "Whats that doing?"

Comment: How reusable is this solution? Can this delay be applied to a textbox? A numeric up-down? Do I need to reimplement every input control just to have delayed values?

Comment: @CameronMacFarland: Yes, yes, yes and yes.  How many __types__ of input control are you thinking of using this technique on?  Compare that number with how many __instances__ of these types you would need to implement Rx the technique on.  My approach here gets implemented per type (and is, as I point out in my comments above, actually quite simple) whereas the "clever" approach needs to be implement per instance.   This answer has many down votes and normally I would delete such an answer however I leave it here because a) it gives devs some pause for thought and b) I still think I'm right.

Comment: > "whereas the "clever" approach needs to be implement per instance" - You'd reuse it the same way you'd reuse any other piece of code, by creating a *method*